# CSS Table with one column taking remaining space

Tags: html, css

I have tried now several things (and looked around here) and nothing worked so far. So I am going to ask.

**What I want:**

I have the following simple HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="small">First column with text</td>
    <td class="extend">This column should fill the remaining space but should be truncated if the text is too long</td>
    <td class="small">Small column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The table itself should be 100% width of the parent container.
I wish the first and last column (`.small`) to be as large as they need to be, so the content can fit into it without a line break (so pretty much what `white-space: nowrap` does). The middle column (`.extend`) should take the rest of the space (so the table will stay within 100% width of its parent container) and the text within `.extend` should be ellipsised before it needs to break to a seconds line.

I've prepared a fiddle for this at http://jsfiddle.net/3bumk/

With these background colors I would expect a result like:

[image: Expected result to see]

Is there any solution for this?

**What I get:**

My problem is, if I can make the text to stay in one row (having no line breaks), the table will always overflow its parent container width (and cause it to be scrollable), before having the idea to ellipsis the text in the middle column.

**What is no solution (I often found):**

It's no solution to set the first and third column to a 'fixed' with (percentage or pixel), because the content will have different length from time to time. It is possible to add as many `div` or `span` as needed (or get rid of the table all together - what I tried first, with `display` and `table` but I didn't find a working solution that way either).

PS: It would be very nice if you could edit the fiddle to a working example, if you know one :-)

**EDIT** I am free to use divs instead of a table too!

Comment: give the center TD with style 100%, not sure

Comment: @Manish that's not working. It still causes the table to overflow its parent boundaries as long as the middle column also has `white-space: nowrap`. I also updated the fiddle to show that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an answer using divs instead of a table: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3bumk/6/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fnl first">First Baby</div>
    <div class="fnl last">Last Guy</div>
    <div class="adjust">I will adjust between both of you guys</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    width: 300px;
}
.first{
    float:left;
    background: red;
}
.last{
    float:right;
    background: orange;
}
.adjust{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Depending on whether the OP can use divs instead of a table a suitable solution... I would avoid words like "perfect solution"...

Comment: In fact I can (and prefer) to use div instead of a table. And this solution has exactly the behavior I described so I will accept it (and hope it will also work in my slightly more complicated real project too).

Comment: One point to pay attention to, is that the `DIV`s are intentionally ordered such that the adjustable length `DIV` is *last*. (I am emphasizing this because the implementation is counter-intuitive to the regular order of HTML tags and may be a common mistake adapting this piece of code.)

Comment: One reason why I needed a `table` solution is so that the width of all the columns/fields are constant across all the rows. That's not possible when using `div`s.

Comment: Not sure how this could be the accepted solution as it was a question about tables!
I don't find this solution very good if it was about divs, but since it was back in 2013 and css grid and flexbox was difficult to get cross browser support and I can see this as an option for the time.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/NhGsf/

By using: `display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; position: absolute; top: 0;`

And setting first and last child to fixed width the middle section will have the rest off the space

Comment: As I mentioned: it's no solution to set a fixed with for last and first column, since their content has no fixed length.

Answer (score 2):

min-width in combination with width:100% seems to work in firefox and chrome:

```
  tr {
    td:first-of-type {
      width: 100%;
    }
    td:last-of-type {
      min-width: 200px;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same challenge and I found the following solution using tables.

The HTML needs to use a DIV in the long column.
The CSS defines your small and extend classes. The hard part being the definition of the extend class.

This gives you the behavior you describe.

### HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="small">First column with text</td>
    <td class="extend">
      <div class="small">This column should fill the remaining space but should be truncated if the text is too long.</div>
    </td>
    <td class="small">Small column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
table {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

table td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table td:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

table td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

table td:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: orange;
}

.extend {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%
}

.small {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I found that only applying the `.extend` class to the `td` is needed for this to work (no `div` needed).  In my case the only element in the expanding `td` is a `range` input.   I also added `white-space: nowrap;` to my others columns to keep them from wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-arrange the columns by moving the longest one at the end then use nested tables.

**CSS**

```
.extend
{
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
td
{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.box
{
    width:1000px;
    border:blue solid thick;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="small">First column with text</td>
     <td class="small">Small column</td>
     <td>
<table>
     <tr>
    <td  class="extend" >This column should fill the remaining space but should be truncated if the text is too long. This column should fill the remaining space but should be truncated if the text is too long. This column should fill the remaining space but should be truncated if the text is too long. This column should fill the remaining space but should be truncated if the text is too long. This column should fill the remaining space but should be truncated if the text is too long.</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

*Except for the ellipsis it is working well.* [See result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Add.png)

Answer (score -1):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dp7Cn/) (or, [alternatively](http://jsfiddle.net/nnT7n/)), you need to set the `max-width` for each table cell:

```
body{
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
table {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
table td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
table td:nth-child(1) {
    background-color:red;
    max-width:100px;
}
table td:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width:100px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
table td:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: orange;
    max-width:100px;
}
```

Comment: close, but not exactly what the OP wants. first and last column should be as slim as possible to give maximum with to the center column.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't behave like I wish (and think I described). If you extend the width of the container, the last and first column are getting larger then their content. Only the middle column should take the space, the first and last should never take more then they need. @Christoph was faster :-)

Comment: Changing the max-width properties should accomplish this- but I dont think the exact behaviour can be achieved with tables :(

Comment: @Tim are you bound to using tables? Because it might be easier to acomplish using a div construct here.

Comment: @TimRoes if you need div solution I already posted have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044452/css-table-with-one-column-taking-remaining-space/20044738#20044738